# Python Libraries - Making them work on PCs that arent mine

Tags: python

Apologies if this is a very stupid question but I am new to python and although I have done some googling I cannot think how to phrase my search query.

I am writing a python script that relies on some libraries (pandas, numpy and others).  At some point in the future I will be passing this script onto my University so they can mark it etc.  I am fairly confident that the lecturer will have python installed on their PC but I cannot be sure they will have the relevant libraries.

I have included a comments section at the top of the script outlining the install instructions for each library but is there a better way of doing this so I can be sure the script will work regardless of what libraries they have?

An example of my script header

```
############### - Instructions on how to import libraries - ###############

#using pip install openpyxl using the command - pip install openpyxl

#########################################################################

import openpyxl
import random
import datetime
```

Comment: This is why we have installers ;)

Comment: create virtual environment n install your packages there and export it .yml file.

Comment: Surely your teacher would have the more common libraries installed? Unless you dug up some really weird ones, somewhere.

Comment: Unless you are sure your teacher is totally clueless in Python, I don't think you need to add the exact instructions on how to install 3rd party extensions. A list of libraries should suffice.

Comment: @DudeCoder, thanks for you response.  I like your solution just been busy

Comment: @Silentbob, Cool

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can firstly make sure that the respective `library` is installed or not by using `try | except`, like so:

```
try:
    import numpy
except ImportError:
    print('Numpy is not installed, install now to continue')
    exit()
```

Now, if `numpy` is installed in his computer, then system will just `import` numpy and will move on, but if `Numpy` is not installed, then the system will `exit` python logging the information required, i.e., `x is not installed`.

And implement the exact same for each and every library you are using.

But if you want to directly install the library which is not installed, you can use this:

*Note: Installing libraries silently is not a recommended way.*

```
import os

try:
    import numpy
except ImportError:
    print('Numpy is not installed, installing now......')
    resultCode = os.system('pip install numpy')

    if resultCode == 0:
        print('Numpy installed!')
        import numpy
    else:
        print('Error occured while installing numpy')
        exit()
```

Here, if `numpy` is already installed, then the system will simply move on after installing that, but if that is not installed, then the system will firstly install that and then will `import` that.

Answer (score 1):

Distributing code is a huge chapter where you can invest enormous amounts of time in order to get things right, according to the current best practices and what not. I think there is different degrees of *rightness* to solutions to your problem, with more rightness meaning more work. So you have to pick the degree you are comfortable with and are good to go.

---

### The best route

Python supports [packaging](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and the safest way to distribute code is to package it. This allows you to specify requirements in a way that installing your code will automatically install all dependencies as well.

You can use existing cookiecutters, which are project-templates, to create the base you need to build packages:

```
pip install cookiecutter
cookiecutter https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage
```

Running this, and answering the ensuing questions, will leave you with python code that can be packaged. You can add the packages you need to the `setup.py` file:

```
requirements = ['openpyxl']
```

Then you add your script under the source directory and build the package with:

```
pip wheel .
```

Let's say you called your project `my_script`, you got yourself a fresh `my_script-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.wheel` file that you can send to your lecturer. When they install it with `pip`, `openpyxl` will be automatically installed in case it isn't already.

Unfortunately, if they should also be able to execute your code you are not done yet. You need to add a `__main__.py` file to the `my_script` folder before packaging it, in which you import and execute the parts of your code that are runnable:

**my_script/my_script/__main__.py:**

```
from . import runnable_script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runnable_script.run()
```

The installed package can then be run as a module with `python -m my_script`

### The next best route

If you really only have a single file and want to communicate to your lecturer which requirements are needed to run the script, send them both your script and a file called `requirements.txt`, which contains the following lines:

```
openpyxl
```

.. and that's it. If there are other requirements, put them on separate lines. If the lecturer has spent any amount of time working with python, they should know that running `pip install -r requirements.txt` will install the requirements needed to run the code you have submitted.

### The if-you-really-have-to route

If all your lecturer knows how to do is entering `python` and then the name of your script, use [DudeCoders approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53297801/962190). But be aware that silently installing requirements without even interactive prompts to the user is a huge no-no in the software-engineering world. If you plan to work in programming you should start with good practices rather sooner than later.